# Align text in a DIV - CSS Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am new to front-end dev, and I am having a bad time trying to simply center the text of this  tag in the div. See in the print; I want the text to be centered, just below the image. I am using bootstrap. Here is the code Im using:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                    <a href="/abrircampanha">
                    <img src="../images/IconAbrirCampanha.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Abrir">
                    
                    </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                
                <a href="/abrircampanha">
                    <img src="../images/IconNovaCampanha.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Abrir">
                    <h3 class="h6 mb-3"> Abrir campanha </h3>

                    
                    </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

To center the text below the image.

Comment: Can you convert your code into a snippet so the problem would reproduce and we could play around with your code in order to provide you a solution?

Answer (score 0):

to center a text with bootstrap, you have to use [text-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment) class